# Subsonic Strips trailing s from Table Name in Object names

Tags: .net, subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have a table called Group_Focus and when we generated our code with Subsonic 2.2 it's calling the object GroupFocu while the files are named GroupFocu.cs and GroupFocuController.cs.  Is there anyway to get it to not strip off the s when it builds the objects?

I'm using the following settings in my Provider settings in the web.config:

includeTableList="^Group"
stripColumnText="s_,d_,b_" 
stripTableText="tbl"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting "fixPluralClassNames" to false on the provider fixed this.  Unfortunately it looks like there were a lot of objects that already had an s stripped so I'll have to deal with GroupFocu or rename it to something else so the s doesn't get stripped.